# Field validation before form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I need to validate an email address in a form but need to submit the form after validating the email address. So, really, I need a way of calling a bit of Javascript that says "yes your email is valid (as in contains all the usual things you'd look for), then submits the form. I have no way around it, I need the form to submit to the action in the form header.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="/captiveportal-test.php">
   <input name="email" type="text">
   <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="$PORTAL_REDIRURL$">
   <input name="mac" type="hidden" value="$CLIENT_MAC$">
   <input name="ip" type="hidden" value="$CLIENT_IP$">

   <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could validate the email address and if the email address contains an @ symbol, submit (so all the post values go through to the action specified)?

Thanks

Comment: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: This looks perfect for what I need. I'll try it, am open to any other suggestions though. Bandwidth is at a premium for those visiting this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<form method = "post" action = "/captiveportal-test.php">
   <input name = "email" type = "text">
   <input name = "accept" type = "submit" value = "Continue">
</form>
```

```javascript
// JavaScript
window.onload = function(){
  var form = document.forms[0],
      pattern = /^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/; 
  form.onsubmit = function(){
    if(!pattern.test(form.email.value)){
      alert("Invalid email"); 
      return false;
    }
  };
};
```

[Working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/falofonabaxe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <input class="email" name="email" type="email">
    <input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validEmail(email) {
    if (!(email && (typeof email === 'string' || email instanceof String))) return false;
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function addEvent(el, name, fn) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        return el.addEventListener(name, fn, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        return el.attachEvent('on' + name, fn);
    }
}

function check(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!validEmail(document.querySelector('.email').value)) {
        alert('Invalid Email');
        return false;
    }
    form.submit();
}

var form = document.getElementById('form');
addEvent(form, 'submit', check);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rurz01Lm/3/**